# Grunt: if external config is not available use default values

Tags: javascript, configuration, gruntjs, yaml

I am loading user configuration file from `user.yml`, but I would like to make a fallback in case that file is not available. Something like:

```
var user = grunt.file.readYAML('user.yml');

if (user != null) {
    console.log(user);
} else {
    user = {
        name: 'Default user',
        email: 'user@gmail.com'
    }
}
```

I am having this code right after the `module.exports = function (grunt) {`, but getting error:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read "user.yml" file (Error code: ENOENT).
```

Answer (score 0):

Grunt will look for the file in a relative path based on your Gruntfile.js file.

So if the file is inside the `conf` folder you need to use:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var user = grunt.file.readYAML('conf/user.yml');

    if(user) {
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        user = {
            name: 'Default user',
            email: 'user@gmail.com'
        }
    }

    grunt.registerTask('default', function(){});
}
```

You can use the absolute path if you prefix it with the absolute path:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var user = grunt.file.readYAML('/tmp/user.yml');

    if(user) {
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        user = {
            name: 'Default user',
            email: 'user@gmail.com'
        }
    }

    grunt.registerTask('default', function(){});
}
```